# what does it mean to extrapolate?

Tags: terminology

Doing an assignment and got up to this question "Is is sensible to extrapolate the  graph   back to the moment  when the population was zero? Explain" Don't know how to answer it because I do not know what this word means

Comment: Continue the image of the graph in its most natural pattern so that the graph now extends to where y (assuming the y axis represents population) is zero

Comment: by graph do you mean line? the population starts at 1 so I am guwaaing th answers would be no

Comment: Yes the line. Presumably this is a graph of population vs time. So as time progresses, the population changes, if you use this pattern to guess what the graph "should" look like, does the line you filled in make sense if you try to "go back in time" to the point when the population was zero?

Answer (score 5):

Images are always very easy to understand.

[image]

When you have a set of data, you can either *interpolate* data within those points or *extrapolate* data that lies beyond. If *x* in this graph represents time, then predicting any associated *y* before the first point or after the last point would be *extrapolating* it.

Mathematically speaking, it's practically the same as interpolation, but since it isn't bounded on both sides by data, it may be less reliable. Although, that does not answer the question of whether it is sensible or not in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

**If the unknown word is "extrapolation"**

Suppose that you have a guess about the law governing the behavior of a function acting on elements of an ordered set. Also, suppose that you know a set of pairs of corresponding inputs and outputs. Then, based on your guess you can find or discover new input output pairs. If the new input, as a member of the ordered set is *between* some old inputs then you interpolate, if it is out somewhere then you extrapolate.